# Origin of the Liouville theorem for harmonic functions

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, cv.complex-variables, ho.history-overview, elliptic-pde

What is the paper where the [Liouville theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function#Liouville%27s_theorem) for harmonic function was first stated? Did it come before or after (or in the same paper) as the [Liouville theorem in complex analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis))?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

References to Liouville go back to his 1847 result that a doubly periodic function without poles is identically constant, which does not yet contain the generalization to either harmonic functions or holomorphic functions.

I quote from [Barry Simon, Harmonic Analysis: A Comprehensive Course in Analysis, Part 3](https://books.google.nl/books?id=YkUACwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) (page 197):

> That any positive harmonic function is constant is due to Bôcher
> (1902), although the theorem is often named after Picard’s rediscovery
> (1923) — there is often reference to the Liouville–Picard theorem.

Bôcher states the theorem in a footnote:

[image]    


- J. Liouville, [*Leçons
  sur les fonctions doublement périodiques*](https://archive.vn/20120711004552/http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/no_cache/en/dms/load/img/?IDDOC=266004) (1847).
- M. Bôcher, [*Singular
  points of functions which satisfy partial differential equations of
  the elliptic type*,](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183417472) Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. (2) 9, (1903),
  455–465.
- É. Picard, *Deux théorèmes élèmentaires sur les singularités des
  fonctions harmoniques*, C. R. Acad. Sci. Paris 176 (1923), 933–935.

Comment: Thank you! What is the relationship between doubly periodic and holomorphic functions (for which the complex Liouville theorem is usually stated)?

Comment: @Zyl --- [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1244416/proving-that-a-doubly-periodic-entire-function-f-is-constant) it is explained that the doubly periodic function is bounded, so it is a special case of a bounded holomorphic function.

Comment: Ok, thanks! What about the more general result on holomorphic functions? Is it in another paper by Liouville?

Comment: the holomorphic result was first announced by Cauchy, in 1844, in response to Liouville's announcement of his doubly periodic result, see [this book](https://books.google.nl/books?id=px_vBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA124)